# Sitecore Analytics - Tracker.Current is null when invoked through a pipeline

Tags: mongodb, sitecore, sitecore-analytics

I have the following method

```cs
GetValue()
{
    var value = Tracker.Current.Contact;
}
```

That always executes.

However when I invoke the above method from the `ItemResolver` pipeline, `Tracker.Current` is always null.

```cs
public class CustomItemResolver : HttpRequestProcessor
{
     public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
     {
        GetValue();
     } 
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tracker is initialized during `startAnalytics` pipeline, which is started by the `renderLayout` pipeline `Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.HttpRequest.StartAnalytics` processor.

If you really need Tracker to be initialized earlier, you can use the following method:

```cs
Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.StartTracking();
```

Remember that Sitecore starts Tracker much later and I'm quite sure there is a reason they don't do this before `ItemResolver`, so you're doing it on your own responsibility.

Comment: Thank you. I moved my code to the Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartTracking.StartTrackingProcessor and that worked for me.